# No devices connected to My Mac(using VMWARE workstation 12) OSX Sierra 10.12.3

Tags: ios, iphone

I am currently trying to connect my iPhone to xcode via VMware. It says it is connected to the VMware workstation not connected to host which is good?

But it is not being read as a device in xcode. `No devices connected to My Mac` is displayed where device selection should be taking place.

Comment: I think you need to map you physical USB port to vmware virtual UBS port.

Comment: This is not a programming question and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.  This question will probably be a better fit on our sister site [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Right I just needed to change it to usb 2.0 in the compatibility settings, reboot the os and it solved it. Sorry for the post I honestly had no idea about the suggested site you Listed.